# Correct usage after result

Tags: grammatical-number

I would like to know which of the following is grammatically correct:

> Another result of the crisis in 2001 *were* rising land and housing prices

or

> Another result of the crisis in 2001 *was* rising land and
> housing prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Another result of the crisis in 2001 **was** rising land and housing prices*" is the correct one. Since we are talking about a singular subject, that is "result".

Comment: Thanks - I was doubting myself!